# Computing round integers

Tags: algorithms, integers

> An integer is round if it is greater than $0$ and the sum of its digits in decimal representation is a multiple of $10$. Find an optimal procedure to compute the $N$−th smallest round integer.

E.g., if $N=2$ then the answer is $28$. As the first round integer is $19$ (note that $1+9=10$) and the second round integer is $28$ (since $2+8=10$).

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It's come up twice so far today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is taken from a live competition, https://www.codechef.com/JUNE19B/problems/KS2

Comment: Don't answer this question, it is taken from an ongoing competition:  https://www.codechef.com/JUNE19B/problems/KS2

Comment: @lulu Can you give me a hint.

Comment: @Somos in this Sum of digits is divisible by 10. not by  divisible by **Multiple** of 10.

Comment: A multiple of 10 is the same as divisible by 10.