# Computing Integers with digit sum a multiple of 10

Tags: number-theory

> An integer is round if it is greater than 0 and the sum of its digits in decimal representation is a multiple of 10. Find an optimal procedure to compute the −th smallest round integer.

E.g., if =2
then the answer is 28. As the first round integer is 19 (note that 1+9=10) and the second round integer is 28 (since 2+8=10).

**This question was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256121/computing-round-integers) a week ago and was closed because it was part of an ongoing competition. The competition has [ended](https://www.codechef.com/JUNE19B/)**

Stackoverflow answers the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563902/find-the-n-th-smallest-round-integer) but mostly the answer involves `finding the pattern` One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564686/3092476) does dive in the math part  but does not explain why?

The algorithm is - 
If the given number $N$ and the sum of digit, $S$ , 
then result always will be - 
    $10*N + (10-S)\mod 10$

**What I am interested to know is how does the mathematics work out for the numbers with digit sum a multiple of 10?**

Comment: Because digit sum of 10*N is the same as digit sum of N.

Comment: add the digits of the number and check whether they are multple of 10 or not, just that simple.

Comment: @AjayMishra I didn't add that detail but I wanted a $O(\log(n))$ solution. A naive search for digit sum $\mod 10$ wouldn't pass all the test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any number $n$. Whatever the sum of its digits is, you can always add one more digit to the right of it and make the sum of digits of the new number divisible by 10. The added digit is unique, it's defined by the value of $n$ (actually, by the sum of it's digits).

Also note that if you add the correct digit to the right of $n$ you always get a smaller number than the number than you get by adding the correct digit to the right of $n+1$. So the order of numbers divisible by 10 is actually defined by $n$.

In other words, if you want to compute the $134^{th}$ round integer, you just start with 134 and add the right digit, which is (2). So the answer is 1342.

In Python:

```
def sum_digits(n): return sum(map(int, str(n)))

def findRoundNumber(order):
    s = sum_digits(order) % 10
    return order * 10 + (0 if s == 0 else (10 - s))

print(findRoundNumber(2))
print(findRoundNumber(123))
print(findRoundNumber(1234))
print(findRoundNumber(12346))
```

And the result is:

```
28
1234
12340
123464
```